# how to list numbers between two numbers in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to create a java program that lists all integers between two variables. One is the lowest(inclusive) the other is the max(also inclusive).
This is my program so far:

```
    int highNum, lowNum;

    //converts and sets user inputs of low and high values to double
    lowNum = Integer.parseInt(minInput.getText());
    highNum = Integer.parseInt(maxInput.getText());
    String output = null;


     for (int i = lowNum + 1; i < highNum; i++)
    output = Integer.toString(i);   

    //outputs sting containing the list of numbers
    outputLabel.setText(output);
```

Before I converted this from a System.out and it worked but when i tried to convert it to a UI with netbeans I can no longer get it to list the numbers.
Before I had this working:

```
    int min, max;
    min = 1;
    max = 10;
    for (int i = min + 1; i < max; i++)
        System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: What is it listing? The wrong numbers or nothing at all? Also, the way you're showing it here, the lowest and highest aren't inclusive, they're exclusive.

Comment: I suggest adding in some debugs. You can do this by printing some stuff to console. Make sure that you're getting the correct numbers from your UI. Also, if you want to make 'output' be a list of _all_ the numbers and not just the final number, you want to use '+=' instead of '=', and maybe a space in there.

Comment: Wait, looking at your comments, are you trying to make a random number or a list of numbers between your numbers? Your comments say one thing and your post another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate each of the values to your `String`, as is you get only the last value.

```
int lowNum = Integer.parseInt(minInput.getText());
int highNum = Integer.parseInt(maxInput.getText());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(lowNum));
for (int i = lowNum + 1; i <= highNum; i++) {
    sb.append(", ").append(i);
}
outputLabel.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8 you can do it in this way using `IntStream`

```
    int lowNum = Integer.parseInt(minInput.getText());
    int highNum = Integer.parseInt(maxInput.getText());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    IntStream.rangeClosed(lowNum, highNum).forEach(no -> {
        sb.append(no);
    });

    outputLabel.setText(sb.toString());
```